# Default selected value rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm sorry this question might seem silly to advanced but here goes

I am trying to set the Piano type in my form to select the preselected value from the database. It currently brings up the first value instead of the preselected value, this is my form entry for the Piano:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :Type %><br>
    <%= form.select(:Type, options_for_select([['Grand', 'Grand'], ['Upright', 'Upright'], ['Console', 'Console'], ['Spinet', 'Spinet']]))  %>
</div>
```

I have tried adding `:selected => Tuning.Type` to the form to preselect the entry but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :Type %><br>
    <%= form.select(:Type, options_for_select([['Grand', 'Grand'], ['Upright', 'Upright'], ['Console', 'Console'], ['Spinet', 'Spinet'], :selected => Tuning.Type]))  %>
</div>
```

I'm a little confused as to whether the select box entries are supposed to be entered in my model or not as this is all new to me and I need help moving forward.

My model reads something like:

```
class Tuning < ApplicationRecord
    validates :Client, presence: true
    validates :Tel, presence: true
    validates :Address, presence: true
    geocoded_by :Address
    after_validation :geocode

end
```

But includes nothing in the way of select values for  'Type', what should I do to show up the preselected type? thank you for your help.

Comment: try this `:selected => form.object.type`, also did you set `@tuning` in controller? so you can use it in view something like `:selected => @tuning.type`

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. I've resolved it to adding simple_forms a choice I didn't make willingly as I didn't want to use a gem to make something I could make manually.